# GAE users.get_current_user() returns None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I am trying to get the current user object in a Google App Engine app however it seems to be returning nothing.

I used the example code at https://github.com/takatama/gae-webapp2-auth/blob/master/handlers.py to write the user handler.

My app logs in succesfully, however get_current_user() is returning NoneType. Is it this function call is in an AJAX POST and the session is not initialised? Do I have to add a decorator somewhere?

Comment: I would post code but I'm not really sure which part to post.

Comment: does it return NoneType or None?

Comment: It returns NoneType: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id' (when I try and call users.get_current_user().user_id())

Comment: Oh, it just returns `None` then: `None.user_id()` - good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `get_current_user` returns `None` if the user is not currently logged in. One normal way to handle this is to first call `user = users.get_current_user()` and then use an `if` block to determine if they are logged in (this example taken from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview)):

```
user = users.get_current_user()
if user:
    greeting = ("Welcome, %s! (<a href=\"%s\">sign out</a>)" %
                (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url("/")))
else:
    greeting = ("<a href=\"%s\">Sign in or register</a>." %
                users.create_login_url("/"))

self.response.out.write("<html><body>%s</body></html>" % greeting)
```

If `get_current_user()` returns `None`, we know that the user is not logged in, so we use `users.create_login_url()` to create a link that will allow the user to authenticate, after which `get_current_user()` will return the `User` object for that user (did I say 'user' enough? :) ).

Comment: I have already presented the login window to the user, and they have authenticated succesfully. My question is why when I call users.get_current_user() after the user being logged in (and I can verify they are logged in because they are accessing a protected part of the app) does the function call return None?

Comment: Or does this indicate a different problem: my app isn't actually logged in?

Comment: @MichaelBates It actually sounds like it is indicative of the user not being logged in. How are you confirming they are actually logged in? Also, are they using their Google account? `get_current_user()` relates to their Google account.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, although I realised I'm not actually using Google's authentication, I'm using webapp2 authentication which is a whole different API

Comment: @MichaelBates Yeah, that is likely your issue though. Good luck getting everything sorted out, and I'm sure if you run into other issues there will be plenty of people around here who will help.

Comment: @MichaelBates did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: users.get_current_user() is for when using Google Account authentication ie. the user logs into your app using their Google Account. I was not using Google Account authentication, and so thats why it was returning None.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the time you have registered is over, and so if youll log to google app engine with different gmail, it will work fine :)